# Can Russell's paradox, Halting problem and Godel's Incompleteness theorem be generalized?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory, computational-mathematics

All these three theorems (I am not 100% sure about the third, but I have heard it has a similar argument with the other two) use self-referentiability as contradiction and they talk about the impossibility to solve everything.

Is there anything that generalizes this concept? I think they actually describe the same object.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes: see [Lawvere's fixed-point theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere's+fixed+point+theorem).

There is an expository paper by Yanofsky covering exactly the results you mentioned (and more): [A Universal Approach to Self-Referential Paradoxes, Incompleteness and Fixed Points](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0305282).

See also [this MathOverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139645/applications-of-lawveres-fixed-point-theorem).

Answer (score 0):

The historical evolution of diagonal argument from set theory to computability and logic is described in:

The Diagonal Argument - a study of cases, International Studies in the Philosophy of Science 6, 191-203 (1992).

The diagonal argument as a uniform principle for generation of set theoretical paradoxes is introduced in:

Cantor's theorem and paradoxical classes, Zeitschr. f. math. Logik und Grundlagen d. Math. 32, 221-226 (1986).