# Does the Löb set contain itself?

Tags: set-theory

[This mathoverflow question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/428366/what-is-the-logical-status-of-the-sentence-combining-the-ideas-of-l%C3%B6b-and-rosser) makes the following 2 points:

- The *Gödel* sentence, "this sentence is not provable", which indeed is not provable in whichever base theory that was used when formulating it and hence is true yet unprovable.
- The *Löb* sentence, "this sentence is provable," is indeed provable, remarkably, by [Löb's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6b%27s_theorem).

In the context of [naive set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_set_theory), let us momentarily consider what one might name the *Löb set*:

$$L \equiv \left\{x\, |\, x\in x\right\}$$

Of course in $ZF$ set theory such a construction is not allowed, as there is no universal set over which a predicate in $x$ can be considered. But at the surface level, unlike the Russell set in which $R\in R\Leftrightarrow R\not\in R$, there is no *immediate* contradiction evident when either statement $L\in L$, or $L\not\in L$, are considered.

#### Questions

Given the [well-known correspondence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3540445/can-russells-paradox-halting-problem-and-godels-incompleteness-theorem-be-gen) between Russell's Paradox and Gödel's second incompleteness theorem, one might consider the correspondence between $L$ and the Löb sentence. Moreover since Löb's theorem shows that the Löb sentence is provable, is there a corresponding theorem in set theory that proves $L\in L$?

Is there a way to even ask this question by improving the definition of $L$ within the context of axiomatic set theory, or is the notion of $L$ dead-on-arrival with no way to survive outside of naive set theory?

Comment: This is a very natural question, but it has been asked before. Briefly: under mild hypotheses, we do indeed get the parallel situation, where the set of all sets that *do* contain themselves contains itself. (We have to leave $\mathsf{ZFC}$ to make this occur, though.)

Comment: I'm not sure why this got a downvote - it *is* a very good question!

Comment: Interesting, thank you for linking to your prior exploration of this question. A similar positive result appears to exist for the question [Will this Turing machine find a proof of its halting?](https://mathoverflow.net/a/427846)

Comment: Also, note that in fact in $\mathsf{ZF}$ the class $\{x: x\in x\}$ **is** a set - it's $\emptyset$. Meanwhile, the alternative set theory $\mathsf{NFU}$ does have self-containing sets but proves that $\{x:x\in x\}$ is not a set (since every set has a complement). The interesting theories are things like $\mathsf{GPK_\infty^+}$ which prove that $\{x:x\in x\}$ is a nonempty set.